# Ionic2 navbar with icons left and right in android

Tags: android, css, angular, ionic2

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar align-title="center" color="primary" hideBackButton>
        <ion-buttons ion-button icon-only start class="card-buttons">
            <button class="card-buttons" (tap)="openMenu()">
                <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
        
        <ion-title class="card-title">        
            {{title | translate}}
        </ion-title>
        <ion-buttons  ion-button icon-only end>
            <button ion-button (tap)="goBack()">
                <ion-icon name="md-arrow-round-back"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button ion-button (tap)="share()">
                <ion-icon name="share" class="ion-md-share"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Menu icon should display left but it displays right. On iOS its ok. In android is this problem:
[image]

can anyone help?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design for both android and windows.

Check this [github issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6844)

> `start` places it to the left of the title in ios and to the right of the title in md and wp mode. If you'd like a button to always be on the left, regardless of the mode, use the `left` property instead.

Try:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar align-title="center" color="primary" hideBackButton>
        <ion-buttons icon-only left class="card-buttons">
            <button ion-button class="card-buttons" (tap)="openMenu()">
                <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>

        <ion-title class="card-title">        
            {{title | translate}}
        </ion-title>
        <ion-buttons icon-only right>
            <button ion-button (tap)="goBack()">
                <ion-icon name="md-arrow-round-back"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button ion-button (tap)="share()">
                <ion-icon name="share" class="ion-md-share"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Also check [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/#buttons-in-a-toolbar)

Comment: Thanks a lot:  :D it solved my problem. wasn't aware of that property